# VAS - Value Added Service

Tags: ads, banner

*I need to confess that i'm neither sure about the title, tags or terms used in the following question. So please be patient, but any edit suggestion would be wellcome!*

Mobile VAS - as defined by Wikipedia are all those services that a SIM owner may use or not in addition to standard comunication protocols. They may be offered trought SMS or special Gateways. Therefore from what I see any service going beyond a SMS and a call may be part of "VASs" offered to the user (Including internet TCP & UDP, VOIP and Premium Services).

But as in most of Customer-End mobile plans Internet cannection and/or VOIP is allready included and they do not dammage the user, let's focus on those called **Premium Services**.

*On Monday my little cousin, texted me, relaying on my IT background, asking me for advice for an accademic research. He asked as follow "...you know what those services that activate mostly themselves and charges a premium on your SIM, what they are and how they work?". At the beginning I was like cool, interesting question. As any of us know them and most of us has been fu***d by one of those. But in short i started feeling frustrated by my ignorance as I actually du not know what they are and even less how they work. But no info are available online.*

Media calls them "Premium Mobile Services", "MVAS" or simply "VAS" that sounds minimalistic. They write long articles about prividers adopting them, about authorities working against them. But no one knows how those 3rd companies "that  are using a mobile provider system" are doing.

I've searched on different Providers website, i've contacted even few of them, asking what are those services, if they have gateways, if companies can simply subscribe and make their own, if those companies are providing actualy an "added value" to the costumer or if ther are simply scamming. But when they replied they were like; "we are not aware such services exist".

I feel like i bounced off a rubber wall, where no one is willing people to know about that. **I can tell my cousin to change topic. But I really hate to give up once I start seeking for knowladge.**

Any of you has more knowladge about those services and is willing to share it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Comment: Wich site will you suggest to move it to?